# Global event handler for UI events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to integrate a clickstream API with a React app. I want to be able to set global event handlers to send clickstream data. For example, creating an event handler for all buttons rendered in React to call `trackButtonClick(name)`. The alternative to this would be to add that call in each individual onClick callback method.

Comment: Maybe give us a sample of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an object that listen for all clicks Events on a high order component like a [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). These events contain important information about the element on which they were fired as well as other properties that could be useful. And then you could stream that data.

If you open **Chrome Developer Tools** and then in the `console` write `window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {console.log(event)})` you should be able to see all events every time you click on the window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with React, but in vanilla JS it could be done like so:

```
window.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target && event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
        // Process clicks..
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't only capture mouse clicks, but also captures other click-like interactions, like someone pressing the enter key on a tab-focused button. (Which is probably desired behavior in most cases)